# authentication between host-named site collection, https and http

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, claims

Here's my situation and I'm wondering what the best way to solve it is.

I have two domains and I'm trying to pass credentials between them.  Maybe it's not possible, but here goes......

Domain One
https://www.domainONE.com

Domain Two
http://www.domainTWO.com

There is ONE web application.  Domain Two is a host-named site collection that resides in the same web application as Domain One.

Authentication is Forms based authentication / Claims.  I want to be able to log into either domain and not have to re-login to the other domain.

Thoughts? Not sure where to go on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume when you say claims you actually mean Claims with Active Directory as user data store, where from your problem, right? If NOT, then you should have no issues as it all handled automatically by the claims - meaning that is all in your connection of the provider!

If domainOne and domainTWO also are related to 2 AD domains, bi-directional trust should be enough for both categories of users to login.

If these are actually just DNS domains, again I see not actual reasons, particular being in the same WEb Application.

I would strongly suggest reading this extremely educative as there are many constraints

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx

One solution would be to build your own authentication pages, Waldek has something in this direction here http://blog.mastykarz.nl/different-login-pages-site-collections-single-web-application/

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I'm using the ldap membership provider, with both sites going against the same Active Directory.  Authentication is setup and working for each domain.

Comment: check my edit for links.

Comment: I was hoping one of those links would be point me in the right direction but haven't had any luck.  This baffles me why I'm not able to push credentials between a host named site collection and another.  I even took https out of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a custom STS to handle user authentication .

Comment: Eric, any idea/hints/links to get started by chance?  Looks like that's my option right now.

Comment: just google 'custom STS', and you can getting start with the [wif training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14347).